# Font is not getting loaded

Tags: css, fonts

I have four `@font-face` rules like this in my css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

And the file structure is as follow:

```
/index.html
 css/
     ...
     fonts.css
     fonts/
           Ubuntu-Regular.ttf
```

When using the browser, I can reach the url `css/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf` and the file is getting downloaded. However, the font it is not loaded by the css. Am I misusing `url()`?

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache ?

Comment: What browsers are you seeing this? You might also need different support for diff browsers like: WOFF and EOT files

Comment: Are you setting the font-family in the CSS for the element(s) you want it on?

Comment: @Riskbreaker: It's Chromium on ArchLinux.

Comment: @Alarid: Uh no, thanks for that. I'll try it for sure but I'm looking for a permanent and safe solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need various versions of the font for it to work in all browsers. You can get all the font files you need, along with the CSS, at the FontSquirrel site:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ubuntu

Just click the "Webfont Kit" link in the menu.

The supplied CSS code looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'UbuntuRegular';
    src: url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.svg#UbuntuRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: This is great advice! It should do for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Just pest below code in your html head tag

**http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>**

& add below element in your css particular class

**font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;**

As because Ubuntu is google font you don't need to use font face. You can directly use this font from  **http://www.google.com/fonts/** -- this site

Comment: This is what I was doing before, but since I'll have to use these files (they are part of an impress.js presentation) on a pc without internet connection, I just wanted to load the fonts locally.

Answer (score 0):

use all font files `.eot` , `.woff` , `.ttf` for all browsers..

```
@font-face {    
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src:url('fonts/Ubuntu.eot') format('eot'), 
          url('fonts/Ubuntu.woff') format('woff'),
          url('fonts/Ubuntu.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

Comment: I don't have all those versions but using @ralph.m suggestion (fontsquirrel) I think I'll solve the problem.